# "Please go back and complete the CAPTCHA" appearing when registering multiple participants for an Event

Tags: civievent, recaptcha

We're on CiviCRM 4.7.25 and Drupal. We have the CAPTCHA and ReCAPTCHA modules enabled, and ReCAPTCHA is enabled on a profile we use for event registration.

We're seeing a new error (which never used to happen!) when registering multiple participants.

Behaviour is:

- User is not logged in to Drupal
- User enters details for Participant 1, and completes Captcha
- User enters details for Participant 2. No captcha appears (good!).  User tries to proceed to next step and encounters alert "Please go back and complete the CAPTCHA at the bottom of this form"
- User can't progress any further with event registration

The only problem being, there is no captcha!

For now, we have disabled Captcha on this profile, having drawn a blank on other fixes.  Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: Have just found this happening on 4.7.27 Drupal 7 site.

Id someone can share the link to a demo site I can try and recreate, but probably not until middle of next week.

Comment: Recreated error in sandbox

raised in jira
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21824

Comment: I've encountered this same issue today, in build CiviCRM 5.23.4 running under Joomla. Was there ever a fix for this?

Comment: Running CiviCRM 5.28.3 on WordPress and having the same problem. Any bug fixes in the works?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug- see comments
2 possible workrounds

1) Limit to single participant registration

2) Create new profile w/o captcha and use this as profile for additional participants

Or as you suggest disable captcha for profile entirely

Comment: Option 2 sounds like the answer to me.

Comment: More an option 1 man myself.